# Always 10 bars on a bar graph even if data runs out at a number indivisible by 10?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm in a bit of a pickle.  I've made a bar graph with d3.js that loads 10 rows of data at a time, each time you click "next" it loads the next 10 rows, and so on.  However, the sets of data I'm working with don't always have a row count divisible by 10, so then I end up with a remainder 2 or 3 bars with odd widths, trying to make up for the missing values.  I want it to load the bars the same width every time, without moving their position, but I also want the x axis to be relative to the amount of data I put in there in case I ever want to change it to load more than 10.

Here's my current code.

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([5, 525], .6)
    .domain(charges);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([150, 0])
    .domain([0, d3.max(swappedData) + ((d3.max(swappedData) / 10) + 10)]);

var rect = g.selectAll('.bar').data(data.slice(a,b));
rect.enter().append('rect');
rect.exit().remove('rect');
rect.attr('class', 'bar')
    .transition().duration(250)
    .attr('width', x.rangeBand())
    .attr('height', function(d) { return 150 - y(d.QuantityCharged) + 2})
    .attr('x', function(d) { return x(d.unslicedCharge) })
    .attr('y', function(d) { return y(d.QuantityCharged) });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different approaches to deal with this (so, this question is maybe *too broad*).

In this approach, I'm merging the current data array with an array made of placeholders:

```
var merged = d3.merge([data,
    d3.range(10 - data.length).map(function(d, i) {
        return {
            name: "bar" + i,
            value: 0
        };
    })
]);
```

Here, the placeholders have a `name` property which start with `bar` and a zero value (since you didn't shared your data structure, I had to create a dummy one).

That merge function will simply complete the data array, until it's length is 10, with our placeholder objects. If the data has already 10 objects, no placeholder will be created. If the data has 4 objects, 6 placeholders will be created, and so on...

Then, it's just a matter of getting rid of the placeholders in the axis generator.

Here is a demo, there are 4 datasets, they are all drawn using the same function:

```js
var data = [
  [{name: "foo", value:10},{name: "foo2", value:40},{name: "foo3", value:30},{name: "foo4", value:10}],
  [{name: "foo", value:10},{name: "foo2", value:40},{name: "foo3", value:40},{name: "foo4", value:90},{name: "foo5", value:10},{name: "foo6", value:70}],
  [{name: "foo", value:50}],
  [{name: "foo", value:10},{name: "foo2", value:40},{name: "foo3", value:40},{name: "foo4", value:90},{name: "foo5", value:10},{name: "foo6", value:70},{name: "foo7", value:10},{name: "foo8", value:40},{name: "foo9", value:30},{name: "foo10", value:10}]
];

data.forEach(function(d) {
  draw(d);
});

function draw(data) {

  var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 100);

  var merged = d3.merge([data, d3.range(10 - data.length).map(function(d, i) {
    return {
      name: "bar" + i,
      value: 0
    };
  })]);

  var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([20, 480], .6)
    .domain(merged.map(function(d) {
      return d.name
    }));

  var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([80, 10]);

  var rects = svg.selectAll("foo")
    .data(merged)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return xScale(d.name)
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return yScale(d.value)
    })
    .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return 80 - yScale(d.value)
    })
    .attr("fill", "teal");

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .orient("bottom")
    .scale(xScale)
    .tickValues(xScale.domain().filter(function(d) {
      return d.substring(0, 3) != "bar"
    }));

  var gX = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0,80)")
    .call(xAxis);

}
```

```css
line,
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```